# Accessing remoteAddress (or request) from validation in Play! 2.3.3

Tags: validation, playframework-2.0

In my form validation method I need to access client ip address.
Is it possible to pass request or ip address into validator implicitly? (without making validation in controller method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was studying this problem for some time and found out it's not possible. In Play [Form](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala) source code you will read that only the [bindFromRequest()](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L76) method has a request in it's scope. The [verifying()](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L496) method lacks access to request and that's why you can't get desired information during a validation process.

I'm afraid you're forced to move this part of validation to a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You meant ad hoc validation?

You could try

```
    play.mvc.Controller.ctx().request().host()
```

I have no Idea if it's going to work.
Tell me if it does

Comment: Haven't you give a try?